# Performance Issue With Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I've 4 components 1 is main component and 3 child components (filter,post and feeds).

And filter and feeds interact with each other when value changes I eventEmit to main component and then send data to other child component.

It works really fine but after if I leave tab open of application after few minutes it started hanging while scrolling and scroll is not smooth till I use ctrl+f5.

Is there any plugin / directive / module which I can use for scroll smoothness.

I'm using ngFor and maximum data is 100 records till now.

Comment: _Is there any plugin / directive / module which I can use for scroll smoothness._ The scrolling isn't smooth due to the page running so much code and you want to add more to fix it? I haven't used anuglar4 but I have used angularJS, when working with performance issues it's usually due to an excessive amount of watches that angular has to do.

Comment: yes that's why I'm using angular 4 because angularjs watchers make application too slow

Comment: Using ChangeDetection.onPush should already help

Comment: @DavidBulté yes I search about it but when I use it in component it will not render anything which comes from service

Comment: When using ChangeDetection.OnPush, the bindings are only evaluated when: an @Input changes or an RxObservable changes, or when a method is triggered by a user event. You can however note to the framework that something else is ready to be re-evaluated through ChangeDetector.markForCheck().

Comment: edit: when an RxObservable changes AND you have applied an async pipe  to it